# How to properly create a HashMap from linear-base (Data.HashMap.Mutable.Linear) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, hashmap, linear-types

I was able to successfully make a `HashMap` from [`Data.HashMap.Mutable.Linear`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-base-0.2.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Mutable-Linear.html) in the [linear-base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-base-0.2.0) package, using the `LinearTypes` extension in GHC 9:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LinearTypes #-}

module Main where

import Data.HashMap.Mutable.Linear
import Data.Unrestricted.Linear

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let m :: (HashMap Int String %1 -> Ur b) %1 -> Ur b
      m = empty 10
  let m' = m (\h -> toList (insert 1 "s" (insert 2 "w" h)))
  let um = unur m'
  print um
```

This looks pretty unergonomic because the entire `HashMap` has to be created all in one go, and after it is created, I get a `[(Int, String)]`. I want to continue having the `HashMap` around to add, update, remove items, etc. In non-linear Haskell, using `unordered-containers`, it looks like:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.HashMap.Strict

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let m :: HashMap Int String
      m = empty
  let m1 = insert 1 "s" m
  -- anywhere else in the code...
  let m2 = insert 2 "w" m1
  print $ m2
```

I wrote the former entirely based on the types I can find in the documentation. `empty` seems to match the `empty` function for non-linear `HashMaps`, but it has type

```
empty :: forall k v b. Keyed k => Int -> (HashMap k v %1 -> Ur b) %1 -> Ur b
```

It says

> Run a computation with an empty `HashMap` with given capacity.

My understanding is that I give it an `Int` as the capacity, and then a "computation" that transforms a `HashMap` into a `Ur b`. The only function I can find that satisfy that type is `toList :: HashMap k v %1 -> Ur [(k, v)]`. The other functions like insert (`insert :: Keyed k => k -> v -> HashMap k v %1 -> HashMap k v`) all return a new `HashMap` (which is actually what I'd expect, but `empty` requires me to return `Ur b`).

Ideally `empty` would return a `HashMap` instead of a `Ur b`, but returning `Ur (HashMap ...)` is fine for me too. There is a function with signature `a -> Ur a`, which is the `Ur` constructor, but if I replace `toList` with it, I get:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘'Many’ with ‘'One’
        arising from multiplicity of ‘h’
    • In the first argument of ‘m’, namely
        ‘(\ h -> Ur (insert 1 "s" (insert 2 "w" h)))’
      In the expression: m (\ h -> Ur (insert 1 "s" (insert 2 "w" h)))
      In an equation for ‘m'’:
          m' = m (\ h -> Ur (insert 1 "s" (insert 2 "w" h)))
   |
24 |   let m' = m (\h -> Ur (insert 1 "s" (insert 2 "w" h)))
   |                ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is to move your interesting hash map computations into the continuation of `empty`, e.g. your second example would be written like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LinearTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

module Main where

import Data.HashMap.Mutable.Linear
import Prelude.Linear hiding (insert)

main :: IO ()
main = print (unur $ empty 10 $ \m ->
  insert (1 :: Int) "s" m & \case
    -- anywhere else in the code...
    m -> insert 2 "w" m & \case
      m -> toList m)
```

It's not pretty, but here's what I meant with doing IO:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LinearTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}

module Main where

import Prelude ((*>))
import Data.HashMap.Mutable.Linear
import Prelude.Linear hiding (insert)

print' :: (Show k, Show v) => HashMap k v %1 -> Ur (IO ())
print' x = toList x & \(Ur x1) -> Ur (print x1)

main :: IO ()
main = unur $ empty 10 $ \m ->
  insert (1 :: Int) "s" m & \case
    m -> dup m & \case
      (m1, m) -> print' m1 & \case
        (Ur io1) -> insert 2 "w" m & \case
          m -> print' m & \case
            (Ur io2) -> Ur (io1 *> io2)
```

Arguably, this is equivalent to doing the IO outside of this function, so I don't know how useful this is.

I guess a better solution would be to have an `empty` function that explicitly allowed a form of IO.

Comment: I have also experimented with `$` and `&` in Prelude.Linear, it just needs some better syntax sugar. Is it possible to do IO within the computations?

Comment: It is possible to do IO, however the built in `print` is not linear. I think ideally you'd want something like `print :: ShowL a => a %1 -> IO a`, but I don't think that exists yet. You can hack something together with [`dup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-base-0.2.0/docs/Data-Unrestricted-Linear.html#v:dup).

Comment: Can you please give me some pointers? dup returns `(HashMap k v, HashMap k v)` but the next "statement" receives another `HashMap k v %1`. How can one of them be converted into linear again?

Comment: Thanks, it works. It's a bit better if they're all aligned in the same column (like do-notation), and the lambda-case can actually be replaced with vanilla destructuring. It shouldn't be too hard to polish it visually especially with RebindableSyntax. The other concern is the need to wrap every non-linear IO function, but oh well.

Comment: Sorry, another question. Is it possible to make decisions based on the IO action? For example, a function that returns `IO Bool`, and then insert a different thing based on that condition?